# Mapbox GL cut off the layer when zooming

Tags: angular, dictionary, layer, mapbox-studio

EDIT:
After optimizing my GeoJson file and uploading the .mbtile created by Tippecanoe, I still have the same problem, to be more specific, depending on how much zoom I do the polygon is cut in one size or another.

[OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSvoZ.png)

[WRONG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZMnK.png)

**I have reproduced the error so you can see the complete code in**
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbxujd?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I am creating a source dynamically from a tileset uploaded in Mapbox Studio. My goal is to show the map boundaries of the provinces of Spain, so that, when I click on one of them, a new layer is created showing only the boundaries of that province.

The loading of data from the tileset works correctly, but when I click on a province to create a new layer **it is cut, as if it were split into two parts**. In fact, sometimes it shows me the cut layer on the left side, and sometimes the one on the right side.

[1. Tileset loaded correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQxr4.jpg)

[2. After clicking on a province, the image is cut off.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJGBS.jpg)

[3. In some cases, the part of the cut shown is the reverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpme2.jpg)

The related code. First I add the source when loading the map:

```
 this.map.on('load', () => {
       this.map.addSource('provinceClicked', {
          'type': 'geojson',
          'data': {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': [] 
            
          }  
        });
```

Then, I create a layer when the user clicks on the province.

```
 // "provincias_fill" is a layer previously created from another source (Works correctly)
 this.map.on('click', 'provincias_fill', (e)=>{ 

  this.map.getSource('provinceClicked').setData({ 
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": e.features[0].geometry.coordinates
        } 
      }
  ] 
  })     
  //Fill layer with blue background
  this.map.addLayer({
    'id': 'mainLine',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'provinceClicked', // reference the data source
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': '#0080ff', // blue color fill
      'fill-opacity': 0.1
    }
  });

  // Add a black outline around the polygon.
  this.map.addLayer({
    'id': 'outline',
    'type': 'line',
    'source': 'provinceClicked',
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'line-color': '#000',
      'line-width': 3
    } 
  });  
});
```

I get this [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/) to create a layer with previous coordinates, and [this one](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/sources/#geojsonsource) to create a source dynamically.

What am I doing wrong? I welcome any comments on this. Happy day to everyone.

Comment: How large is your GEOJson source? Does this still happen with smaller layers?

Comment: Much appreciated for your comment. It is very possible that the problem comes from there. Previously I created a layer with a polygon made with MapboxDraw and it worked fine.

I just realized that the detection of cities is not very accurate, and from what I've read, it may be due to a large geojson size. So, I should to read this documentation [working with large geojson](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/working-with-large-geojson-data/) and try again. I'll update the post with any news.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning unique identifiers (as key: value) to every province in your dataset. Then signal Mapbox to use this identifier when loading features, by providing the key through promoteId in `addSource()` on load.

E.g.:

```
 this.map.on('load', () => {
     this.map.addSource('provinceClicked', {
       'type': 'geojson',
       'data': {
         'type': 'FeatureCollection',
         'features': [] 
       },
       promoteId: {"sourceLayerId": key}
  });
```

Also see [Mapbox Layer features duplicate IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493095/mapbox-layer-features-duplicate-ids)